# SWRealViewController over UINavigationBar subview hides UINavigationItems

Tags: ios, ios8, swrevealviewcontroller

When I layer SWRevealViewController over a normal UIViewController's view, to achieve a sliding left menu effect, it works as intended.

However, when this view controller is embeded on a UINavigationController, it overlays the navigation bar and hides the image and left and right BarButtonItems.

I'd appreciate some help finding a workaround.

This is how I'm adding this buttons:

```
UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-back"]
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                    target:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
UIBarButtonItem *saveExitButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"out"]
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                    target:self action:@selector(saveExit)];

self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveExitButtonItem;
```

Added this repository to show my point I'm using this component https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController:

```
https://github.com/AresDev/revealtest.git
```

Main.storyboard is working, just change in project settings the main interface to NonWorking.storyboard to see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, the navigation item that I have to add the buttom items is actually the RevealViewController navigation item.

```
UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-back"]
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                target:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

UIBarButtonItem *saveExitButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"out"]
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                target:self action:@selector(saveExit)];

self.revealViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;
self.revealViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveExitButtonItem;
```

Answer (score -1):

This what I understood from your question: You are trying to put together a navigation drawer view controller. If so then you could refer to: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

If not then please elaborate your query.

Comment: I didn't explain well so I edited my question add a repo with my problem but I will try your suggestion. Thks!

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the problem persists, even with this new drawer.